# Presenting an image with a transparent background

Tags: html, transparency

I am working on a little HTML/Css learning project. Anyway, I have an image that I edited to have no background. What I really did was to 'select by color' the background and then cut it. I think it means having a transparent background.

Suppose I'm right, why do I see it with a white background when I put it on my html page?
And if I'm wrong, how do I go about achiving transparency?

Thanks!

P.s. I've attached the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adFMv.jpg)

Comment: Saving as `.jpg` converts the transparency to white. Save it as a `.png` in your editor to keep the transparency.

Comment: `.bmp` doesn't have transparency AFAIK though.

Comment: @Pekka You're right; I was thinking of `.gif`.

Comment: You can save it as `.gif` with transparent background.

Comment: or You can try this
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Comment: the transperency will come if you save the image as a png file